# Natviescript Angular2 HTTP

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am working on angular2 + nativescript project using this seed project and I am not able to make a simple HTTP POST call using this code

```
return this.http.post(`${AppConfigService.API_PATH}/login`, body, options)
          .map(res => res.json())
          .catch((err: any) => {
            return Observable.throw(err);
          });
```

this code works fine in normal angular2 app but in native script it gives the error:
Response with status: 200 for URL: null

I have also logged the issue on Github: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2536

Comment: Have you solved this problem ? I'm with this same problem and i dont know what to do.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the NativeScript HTTP module, [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/http) are the docs. The different mobile platforms work differently to a regular browser, hence you need a {N} core module to manage the different platform-specific APIs. 
A JSON POST would look like this:

```
var result;

http.request({
    url: "https://httpbin.org/post",
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    content: JSON.stringify({ MyVariableOne: "ValueOne", MyVariableTwo: "ValueTwo" })
}).then(function (response) {
    // result = response.content.toJSON();
    // console.log(result);
}, function (e) {
    // console.log("Error occurred " + e);
});
```

and you must ensure you use `var http = require("http");`

Answer (score -1):

you can use nativescript http with angular , following example:

first import http serves in the top of the service component

```
var http = require("http");
```

in the sevice.ts file ,you need to convert the http promise to observable .

```
//GET Example
    getList(): Observable<News[]> {
        return Observable.fromPromise(
                    http.getJSON(serverConfig.apiUrl+"news")
                ).map(function(res:any) {
                    console.log('finished sendign request'); 
                    return res as News[] 
                } );

    }


//POST EXAMPLE

submitFormData(data): Observable<Forms> {
        let url:string=serverConfig.apiUrl+"forms/";
        let headers:any = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer '+this.appSettings.getString("access_token")};
        let req:any={
            url:url,
            method: "post",
            headers:headers,
            content: JSON.stringify(data)
        };

        return Observable.fromPromise(
                    http.getJSON(req)
                ).map(function(res:any) {
                    return res as Forms 
                } );
    }
```

then you can subscribe to the observeable as you used befor,

```
this.newsService.getList().subscribe((res) => {
    this.news= res;
});
```

Note :  now you can remove the import statment of angular http since its not needed